# Objective-C CLLocationManager is nil all of a sudden

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

I have done the following in my .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <DTDeviceDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
{

    CLLocation *currentLocation;

}

@end
```

and here is my .m file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    AVAudioPlayer *_audioPlayer;
}

@end


@implementation ViewController
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    currentLocation = nil;

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *) newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    if (currentLocation == nil)
        currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        Long.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        Lat.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}

@end
```

I put break points in `viewDidLoad` and in `didUpdateToLocation` in `viewDidLoad` it says `locationManager` is nil and my break points in `didUpdateToLocation` do not get hit, this was working before. All of a sudden it does not work.

NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription and NSLocationWhenINUseUsageDescription and privacy - location usage description and defined in my .plist file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems. You have the `locationManager` ivar declared in both the header file and in the class implementation. Remove it from the header file.

The real big issue is that you never create the location manager.

In `viewDidLoad` you need:

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

On a side note, you should remove all of the protocols from the `@inteface` line in the header file and add them to the `@interface` line in the .m (for the class extension).

In other words, the .h should be:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

And the .m should be:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ViewController () <DTDeviceDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate, UIAlertViewDelegate>
{
    AVAudioPlayer *_audioPlayer;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
{
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
}

// and the rest
```

There is no reason to put all of those private details in the public header file.